A Proof about Combination
$\newcommand{\posintset}{\mathbb{Z}^{+}}$
$\newcommand{\domain}[1]{\operatorname{dom}\left(#1\right)}$
$\newcommand{\cardinal}[1]{\abs{#1}}$
$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$
I would like to prove the following statement: Let $n, k \in \posintset$ and $n \geq k$, $k > 0$, $\sigma$ be a permutation for $\left\{0, \dots, n - 1\right\}$ and $u$ be a sequence of size $n$. Then
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{\substack{s \subseteq u\\\cardinal{s}=k}}\prod_{i \in \domain{s}} s_{i} = \sum_{\substack{s \subseteq u \circ \sigma\\\cardinal{s}=k}}\prod_{i \in \domain{s}} s_{i}.
\end{equation*}
Intuitively, this statement says that given an $n$-tuple, no matter how we shuffle the tuple, the summation of product of combinations of $k$-elements do not change. Obviously, this is true. I am thinking about proving the statement using induction, but am having some technical difficulty from reasoning from $n$ to $n + 1$.

$\newcommand{\posintset}{\mathbb{Z}^{+}}$
$\newcommand{\powerset}[1]{\mathcal{P}\left(#1\right)}$
$\renewcommand{\restriction}{\mathord{\upharpoonright}}$
$\newcommand{\restrict}[2]{{#1}\restriction_{#2}}$
$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$
$\newcommand{\domain}[1]{\operatorname{dom}\left(#1\right)}$
$\newcommand{\cardinal}[1]{\abs{#1}}$
$\newcommand{\range}[1]{\operatorname{range}\left(#1\right)}$
Actually, no need for induction.
As $\sigma$ is a permutation, $\sigma$ is bijective. Let $s \subseteq \domain{u}$ and $\cardinal{s} = k$. Let $x \in s$. As $\sigma$ is both injective and surjective, there is some unique $y \in \domain{u}$ such that $\sigma\left(y\right) = x$. Thus, there is some unique $t$ such that $t \subseteq \domain{u}$, $\cardinal{t} = k$ and $\range{\restrict{\sigma}{t}} = s$. Thus, there is some mapping $f$ such that for any $x$, $x \in \domain{f}$ if and only if $\cardinal{x} = k$ and $x \subseteq \domain{u}$ and for any $x \in \domain{f}$, $\range{\restrict{\sigma}{f\left(x\right)}} = x$. We fix this $f$. It is clear that $f$ is a bijection. Then for any $s$, if $s \subseteq \domain{u}$ and $\cardinal{s} = k$, then
\begin{equation*}
\prod_{i \in s} \left(\restrict{u}{s}\right)\left(i\right) = \prod_{i \in f\left(s\right)} \left(u \circ \left(\restrict{\sigma}{f\left(s\right)}\right)\right)\left(i\right) = \prod_{i \in f\left(s\right)} \restrict{\left(u \circ \sigma\right)}{f\left(s\right)}\left(i\right).
\end{equation*}
Consequently,
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{\substack{s \subseteq \domain{u}\\ \cardinal{s}=k}} \prod_{i \in s} \left(\restrict{u}{s}\right)\left(i\right) = \sum_{\substack{s \subseteq \domain{u}\\ \cardinal{s}=k}} \prod_{i \in f\left(s\right)} \restrict{\left(u \circ \sigma\right)}{f\left(s\right)}\left(i\right) = \sum_{\substack{s \subseteq \domain{u \circ \sigma}\\ \cardinal{s}=k}} \prod_{i \in f\left(s\right)} \restrict{\left(u \circ \sigma\right)}{f\left(s\right)}\left(i\right).
\end{equation*}
Now, let
\begin{equation*}
A = \left\{t \in \powerset{\posintset} \vert \textrm{there is some } s \textrm{ such that } s \subseteq \domain{u \circ \sigma}, \cardinal{s} = k \textrm{ and } t = f\left(s\right)\right\}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
B = \left\{s \in \powerset{\posintset} \vert s \subseteq \domain{u \circ \sigma} \textrm{and} \cardinal{s} = k\right\}.
\end{equation*}
First, let $x \in B$. By definition, $x \subseteq \domain{u \circ \sigma}$ and $\cardinal{x} = k$. Assume that $x \not\in A$. Then for any $s$, if $s \subseteq \domain{u \circ \sigma}$ and $\cardinal{s} = k$, then $f\left(s\right) \neq x$. This contradicts the fact that $f$ is surjective. Thus, $x \in A$. Consequently, we have $B \subseteq A$. Next, let $x \in A$. Then there is some $s$ such that $s \subseteq \domain{u \circ \sigma}$, $\cardinal{s} = k$ and $x = f\left(s\right)$. Obviously, we have $x \in B$. Thus, $A \subseteq B$. As a result, we have $A = B$.
Thus, we have
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{\substack{s \subseteq \domain{u \circ \sigma}\\ \cardinal{s}=k}} \prod_{i \in f\left(s\right)} \restrict{\left(u \circ \sigma\right)}{f\left(s\right)}\left(i\right) = \sum_{\substack{s \subseteq \domain{u \circ \sigma}\\ \cardinal{s}=k}} \prod_{i \in s} \left(\restrict{\left(u \circ \sigma\right)}{s}\right)\left(i\right).
\end{equation*}
Consequently, we have
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{\substack{s \subseteq \domain{u}\\ \cardinal{s}=k}} \prod_{i \in s} \left(\restrict{u}{s}\right)\left(i\right) = \sum_{\substack{s \subseteq \domain{u \circ \sigma}\\ \cardinal{s}=k}} \prod_{i \in s} \left(\restrict{\left(u \circ \sigma\right)}{s}\right)\left(i\right).
\end{equation*}
